# Как правильно говорить: «две пятьсот» или «два пятьсот»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные, род

Очень часто возникает неопределенность: "два пятьсот" или "две пятьсот"?
В каких случаях говорить "два пятьсот", а в каких — "две пятьсот"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, что и это вопрос с подвохом или на сообразительность.

[§ 3. Следы родовых различий в числительных *один, два, оба, полтора*](https://slovari.ru/default.aspx?p=5310&0a0=11)

> Формы рода различаются в именительном и винительном падежах: *два — две*; форма *две* — женского рода, форма *два* — мужско-среднего. Но грамматический род здесь выражается так необычно, что в этом отношении слово *два — две* ближе к другим числительным, лишенным форм рода, чем к именам существительным или прилагательным. В самом деле, слово *два — две* в именительном и винительном (неодушевленном) падежах заимствует свой род от следующего за ним в форме родительного падежа имени существительного, с которым оно не согласуется ни в числе, ни в падеже (например: *два солдата, две колхозницы* и т. п.). В косвенных падежах у этого числительного родовых различий нет: формы *двух, двумя* и т. д. лишены рода. К слову *два — две* примыкает числительное *оба — обе*.

• **Тысяча** — она, две (чего? Р. п., ж. р.) тысячи; две тысячи пятьсот —> ***две** пятьсот*.

*― Такие котлы в магазине стоят **две пятьсот*** [две тысячи пятьсот долларов] (Эдуард Лимонов. Подросток Савенко).
*— Ну... учитывая то, что длина полосы **две пятьсот**...*[две тысячи пятьсот метров] (Денис Окань. Философия полёта. Небесные истории — 6).

•• **Миллион** — он, два (чего? Р. п., м. р.) миллиона; два миллиона пятьсот тысяч —> ***два** пятьсот.*
**Километр, килограмм** — он, два (чего? Р. п., м. р.) километра, килограмма; два километра пятьсот метров, два килограмма пятьсот граммов —> ***два** пятьсот.*

*Помните, друзья, что рубеж поисков ― на глубине **два пятьсот*** (Сергей Жемайтис. Большая лагуна); *Беременность протекала без осложнений, говорят врачи, девочки родились с весом **два сто** и **два пятьсот**...* (из статьи).